# По какой причине Backend редактор WPBakery Page Builder визуально не работает?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При редактировании страницы (или создании новой) переключаюсь на backend редактор от Wp Bakery.

Могу добавить элемент, но визуально он не отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя шорткоды добавляются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Wordpress последней версии на сегодняшний день, php 7.2.

Отключать плагины, менять тему пробовал, не помогает. Ошибки ни js, ни php не выдает.

P.S. Данная проблема началась после переезда на другой хостинг (т.е. на старом все работало как положено), а на новом почему-то не работает (даже заново подминал сайт с 0).

Может кто с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой.
В моём случае мешал вывод ошибок PHP, хотя визуально их не было видно. Решение - в файл wp-config.php в самый конец добавить:

```
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Работает не на всех хостингах. Если не сработает - ищите способ отключить вывод PHP предупреждений и ошибок.